# deserialize inconsistent json to object c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

Can someone tell me how to deserialize JSON to a C# (without using C# dynamic) object when JSON string is having dynamic array of data?

Given below JSON is having Boxes object and it can contain Array of fashion items (It can be pants, sweater, shoes,...etc)

```
{
  "task": {
    "id": 269740275,
    "status": "success",
    "error": null,
    "date_created": "2017-02-16T10:33:41.827688Z",
    "date_updated": "2017-02-16T10:33:42.417778Z",
    "data": {
      "width": 1062,
      "boxes": {
        "top-shirt": [
          {
            "xmin": 0.249980241060257,
            "ymin": 0.1535395532846451,
            "ymax": 0.476559966802597,
            "xmax": 0.6146213412284851,
            "proba": 0.9977585077285767
          }
        ],
        "shoe": [
          {
            "xmin": 0.3686676025390625,
            "ymin": 0.9223044514656067,
            "ymax": 0.9838011264801025,
            "xmax": 0.4768480360507965,
            "proba": 0.9748706817626953
          }
        ],
        "pants": [
          {
            "xmin": 0.3451904654502869,
            "ymin": 0.4616038501262665,
            "ymax": 0.909162700176239,
            "xmax": 0.6047541499137878,
            "proba": 0.9983627200126648
          }
        ]
      },
      "height": 1503
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `boxes` object is not an “Array of fashion items ”; it is a record with arbitrary fields that contain arrays. You cannot deserialize it to a strongly-typed array because it isn't one. You either need to handle `boxes` as a stream of properties, or use LINQ to return anonymous types; [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) can do both.

Comment: Please can you give me any example for reading this JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to handle the dynamic part of the JSON (boxes).

Define your classes like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Task task { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public object error { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_updated { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int width { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<Item>> boxes { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public double xmin { get; set; }
    public double ymin { get; set; }
    public double ymax { get; set; }
    public double xmax { get; set; }
    public double proba { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this:

```
RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sxz8P3

Answer (score 2):

Use NuGet to fetch the Newtonsoft.JSON package.

Then you can use linq-to-json to handle this kind of data object.

For example, assuming your example JSON string is stored in `input`,

```
var message = JObject.Parse(input);
var width = (int)message["task"]["data"]["width"];
var height = (int)message["task"]["data"]["height"];
Console.WriteLine(width + " " + height);

var boxes = message["task"]["data"]["boxes"];
foreach (var box in boxes.Children<JProperty>()) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(box.Name)  ;
}
```

This is pretty close to Javascript and works well.

Answer (score 0):

I think O. Jones provided the easiest solution, using Newtonsoft, Newtonsoft is literally the best possible way to do anything with JSON in C# and without any headaches.

Here's one of the simplest examples

```
string json_string = @"{
                  Firstname: ""Jane"",
                  Lastname: ""Doe"",
                  Age: 36,
                  IsEmployed: true,
                  IsMarried: true,
                  Children: 4
              }";
              
var person = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json_string);

Console.WriteLine(person.Forename);
Console.WriteLine(person.Lastname);
Console.WriteLine(person.Age);
Console.WriteLine(person.IsEmployed);
Console.WriteLine(person.IsMarried);
Console.WriteLine(person.Children);
```

It generates objects on the fly, no matter the structure!

I wrote a simple, easy-to-follow article here https://turmanauli.medium.com/a-complete-guide-for-serializing-json-to-dynamic-objects-on-the-fly-in-c-7ab4799f648d
about how to use Newtonsoft in your Visual Studio project.